# Manual migartion Data model

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to core data. when ever i add an entity or delete any entity, my app is getting crashed and i am loosing the data. I gone through the apple docs and found that when ever changes are made to model the we need migrate the current version to new version. Light weight migration will not support for enitity deletion sort of things. Can anyone lemme know what is source and destination model? how should i do manual migration? In my app i frequently change the data model. If i delete and run the app users are loosing their data. Please lemme know how to do manual migration in detail?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't have to migration it by yourself.
The only thing you need to do is **add a new Data model version**, **select the new version as current version**, and then you can edit your new version now, Core Data will do the migration work for you.

Comment: For small changes coredata will find the model and migrates the data, but if there are changes like one entity is deleted then how the store can identify the model. According to apple docs, if learnt that we need to use manual migration for this. but how to use the manual migration is the point for me? and any example that you can give?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of modify are you trying to do. But things like delete an entity is not required for manual migration, Core Data will do it for you.

Comment: Ok for example i have an entity like Personal information which contain all the personal details with address, now i want the entity to be split into two different entities one is information and the second one is Address. I want existing record to me mapped without any lose of data. This is what i want. any ideas?

Comment: I see. Lightweight migration will only deal with the schema but not the data. In this case, you'd better do not change your `Personal information` entity but add a new one called `address`. After the lightweight migration have done its job, you should manually move those addresses info into the new entity by using a for loop for example. Or you can Customizing the Migration Process by following the document here: http://bit.ly/pbMxYA . But I have to say let Core Data handle the schema thing and we handle the data thing is much easier. :)

Comment: Thanks alot for your support... :-). Will get back to you if any doubts

Comment: You are welcome. If you feel this answer is useful, a vote up or select it as the correct answer is appreciate. ;)